# overflow is not working in Opera?

Tags: html, css, textarea

How to `break the words` and `disable the scroll bar` of `textarea` when content exceeds? Problem in  Opera only.

My `textarea` looks like,

[image]

The `overflow:auto` property is works in all browsers except Opera.

My CSS will be,

```
#message {
    width: 99.5%;
    height: 60px;
    border: none;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    border-color: #6495ED;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;


    }
```

How to resolve this.Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: none`?

Comment: Which version of Opera? Works fine for me in ver. 12.12

Comment: @Morpheus tried and not worked.

Comment: @Kite Player mine is fine as well, opera 12.02. http://jsfiddle.net/BRN8H/

Comment: @Morpheus Am I want to open this link in opera ?

Comment: @Morpheus This worked for me in opera 12.10. Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    {
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
  white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
  word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
}
```